# Why does findbugs not detect when streams are not closed?

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, findbugs, spotbugs

I've a usecase where I'm creating an `InputStream` in one class & passing it to another. If I remove the `finally` block where I close the stream, it does not get detected in findbugs. Why is that?

```
Class A {
  public static void methodA(InputStream is) {
    // Do something.
    // The stream is NOT closed.
  }
}

Class B {
  public void methodB(Sting filePath) {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
    A.methodA(fis);
  }
}
```

Ideally, findbugs should have detected that the stream is not closed in this use case. But, it doesn't & I'm curious to know why!

Comment: I assume it's a bug because `FileInputStream#finalize` doesn't even call `FileInputStream#close`.